# How do I use a JUnit Parameterized runner with a varargs constructor?

Tags: java, junit

I wrote a mockup example to illustrate this without exposing anything confidential. It's a "dummy" example which does nothing, but the problem occurs in the test initialiser.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ExampleParamTest
{
 int ordinal;
 List<String> strings;

 public ExampleParamTest(int ordinal, String... strings)
 {
  this.ordinal = ordinal;
  if (strings.length == 0)
  {
   this.strings = null;
  }
  else
  {
   this.strings = Arrays.asList(strings);
  }
 }

 @Parameters
 public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
  return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
    {0, "hello", "goodbye"},
    {1, "farewell"}
  });
 }

 @Test
 public void doTest() {
  Assert.assertTrue(true);
 }
}
```

Basically I have a test constructor which accepts multiple arguments for a local list variable and I want to populate this through an array initialiser. The test method will handle the local list variable correctly - I have removed this logic to simplify the test.

When I write this, my IDE has no complaints about syntax and the test class builds without any compile errors. However when I run it, I get:

```
doTest[0]:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
doTest[1]:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

What exactly has gone wrong here, and how do I correctly use this pattern?

Comment: What is doTest and what data does it hold?

Comment: In this example, doTest is just a dummy test to allow this testsuite to execute in JUnit. The problem is not in the test code, as you will see when you try to run this test as it stands; despite the fact that it has an almost empty test body, it still fails to run due to the aforementioned initialisation error.

Comment: I added part of the stacktrace that I see when I run your test to make it clear that the error is happening when the varargs constructor is invoked. If that's different from what you're seeing, feel free to change it or revert it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can't test it right now but I guess, if you invoke a method or a constructor with variable arguments, you have to invoke it with an array instead of a variable list of values.

If I'm right, then this should work:

```
@Parameters
 public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
  return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
    {0, new String[]{"hello", "goodbye"}},
    {1, new String[]{"farewell"}}
  });
 }
```

**Some explanation**

On source code level, we can write

```
test = ExampleParamTest(0, "one", "two");
```

The compiler will convert this to an array of Strings. JUnit uses the reflection and invocation API, and from this perspective, the constructors signature is

```
public ExampleParamTest(int i, String[] strings);
```

So to invoke the constructor - and that's what JUnit is doing internally - you have to pass an integer and a String array.

Comment: You're right, this did work. But it's not universally true. Normally, I could write something like:

    myTest = new ExampleParamTest(0, "hello", "goodbye");

This is the entire point of variable argument methods. Why then does this not work in my example?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround given by @marcphillip in this [JUnit feature request](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/2256) works great for now:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource({"1,a", "1,a,b,c"})
void testAbc(int arg1, @AggregateWith(VarargsAggregator.class) String... elements) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(elements));
}

static class VarargsAggregator implements ArgumentsAggregator {
    @Override
    public Object aggregateArguments(ArgumentsAccessor accessor, ParameterContext context) throws ArgumentsAggregationException {
        Class<?> parameterType = context.getParameter().getType();
        Preconditions.condition(parameterType.isArray(), () -> "must be an array type, but was " + parameterType);
        Class<?> componentType = parameterType.getComponentType();
        return IntStream.range(context.getIndex(), accessor.size())
                .mapToObj(index -> accessor.get(index, componentType))
                .toArray(size -> (Object[]) Array.newInstance(componentType, size));
    }
}
```

***Update:*** I added this tweak to give an empty array when there is nothing provided after the last comma:  ***Update2:*** I realized this is not needed: Just leave off the trailing comma (which I'd assumed was mandatory) in order to pass in an empty vararg array.

```
        if (result.length == 1 && result[0] == null) {
            return Array.newInstance(componentType, 0);
        }
        return result;
```